# How can I increase the size of the string that an external debugger visualizer can display?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2, debuggervisualizer

I am once again writing an external debugger visualizer, and am running into a wall. There appears to be a limit to the size of the string that the debugger visualizer can return.

The TStrings debugger visualizer that shipped with Delphi 2010 had a limit of 4K. In a response to a question posted on Embarcadero's newsgroups, Ewe Schuster [replied](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.ide/200910/0910065447.html) that "You can increase the buffer a little bit, but AFAIR the actual limitation is in IOTAThread.Evaluate with a limit of about 12k chars."

My debugger visualizer is based on the code of the TStrings debugger visualizer, and I can see that the implementation of the TFrame's Evaluate method includes the following declaration of ResultStr, which is used to return the string returned from the IOTAThread.Evaluate call:

```
  ResultStr: array[0..4095] of Char;
```

I had hoped that increasing the size of this buffer would help, but no luck.

What can I do, if anything, to increase the size of the string that my external debugger visualizer can display?

Comment: As a workaround, can you create a visualizer for PString?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same limited patience for that limit...
So I made a debug visualizer that work around the limitation mostly by creating a MemoryStream in the debugged process to hold the string result of the Expression, then use something like

```
CurProcess.ReadProcessMemory(StrToInt(SrcMemoryAddr), DstMemStream.Size, DstMemStream.Memory^);
```

to copy it into a visualizer's MemoryStream. Then you can do whatever you want to display it (for instance formatting it for human reading if it's an XML string like a CLientDataSet.XMLData).

There are few tricks depending if the Expression is a const string, a var, or needs evaluation etc...

My FGStringVisualizer is not 100% satisfying, which is why I haven't published it yet on my blog, but as it does 99% of what I need, I didn't take the time to clean it a bit and publish it even "as-is". But if there is a need I can certainly do it with all needed disclaimers...

Update: 
It's the same idea that I used for my FGStringListVisualizer that I presented at the last DelphiLive. By the way, this one also might be worth putting on my blog as I made a few improvements since.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. However, I do not completely understand the answer. I use CurProcess to get CurrentThread, and then call Evaluate on CurrentThread to get the value of the expression (which is a string in my case). How does the code you provided work into this equation. Is your ScrMemoryAddr variable the out ResultAddr parameter of Evaluate. and the DstMemStream your visualizer's TMemoryStream?

Comment: I call `Evaluate` to Create the MemoryStream in CurProcess: `if not Evaluate(DebugSvcs, CurProcess, CurThread, 'NativeInt(TMemoryStream.Create)', SrcMemStreamAddr)then`. Then I use `Evaluate` again to put the string into it: `if not Evaluate(DebugSvcs, CurProcess, CurThread,
                      'TMemoryStream(' + SrcMemStreamAddr + ').Write((' + FExpression +
                      '), Length(' + FExpression + ')*SizeOf(Char))', CurSizeResult) then`... That's where it gets murky depending on the nature of  Expression...

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but I cannot find an Evaluate method that takes an IOTADebuggerServices, IOTAProcess, and IOTAThread as its first three parameters. Is this a custom method you wrote. If not, on which interface will I find this version of Evaluate?

Comment: You're right. It's based on Delphi sample (`TStringListViewerFrame.Evaluate`), but I moved the DebugSvcs, CurProcess and CurThread outside of it's scope to reuse them...

Comment: @François, rather than use `Evaluate()` twice to create a `TMemoryStream` and `Write()` to it separately, have you tried calling `Evaluate()` just once and pass `FExpression` to the `TStringStream` constructor?  `Evaluate()` has a lot of overhead to it, so you should minimize its use.

Comment: @Remy. You don't necessarily have the `TStringStream` class in the debugged project, while, as soon as you include `Classes`, you have `TMemoryStream` available. And `TMemoryStream` does not have a 1 step constructor-writer like `TStringStream`...

Comment: `TStringStream` is also in the `Classes` unit. And yes, I know `TMemoryStream` does not have a 1-step writing constructor, that is the point I was making.  If you can construct a stream and write to it in a single call to `Evaluate()`, the better the performance.

Comment: @Remy, If the project does not use `TStringStream`, it is simply not linked into the debugged project, while `TMemoryStream` is there due to the initialization clause. That's the point I was making. :)

Comment: @François when I try "Evaluate('NativeInt(TMemoryStream.Create)'" the eval result is erDeferred and never finish! any idea?

Comment: @François, do you have the source for your visualizer? Would love to play with it.