# How can I increase the size of the string that IDE debugger visualizer can display?

Tags: delphi, debugging, ide, debuggervisualizer

How can I increase the size of the string that IDE debugger visualizer can display? 
At the moment the limit is 2K (I think).

I am thinking in finding the source code for the current string visualizer and modifying it to show more lines and registering it as a new visualizer. Is this the correct or the cumbersome solution?

Comment: See [How can I increase the size of the string that an external debugger visualizer can display?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9521596/576719).

Comment: Hi Lu. I have already seen that question. But it is not not related to the Delphi IDE visualizer but to an external vis.

Comment: See http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40268 how to include your own debugger visualiser into the IDE.

Comment: @LURD-I was thinking about something like that but it seems odd to have the same visualizer twice. I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking in finding the source code for the current string visualizer and modifying it to show more lines and registering it as a new visualizer. Is this the correct or the cumbersome solution?

That source code is not available to you. It's buried in the bowels of the IDE's debugger. As I see it your options are:

1. Modify the existing visualizer at runtime, for instance using a detour.
2. Replacing the visualizer with one that serves your needs.

Comment: Damn it. Why the simple solution always always has strings attached :) ?  ---------  I don't really know how to do the detour but I will try the second solution proposed. I will use the visualizer proposed by LURD. Thanks David.