# debug visualizer for delphi 6

Tags: delphi, debugging

I'm working  at delphi 6 project. I am looking for a simple debug visualizer tool.
For example I want to show items inside the object like visual studio, can show sub items in object.

[image: inline pic]

Comment: You can use [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Evaluate/Modify). `Ctrl+F7` -> Inspect

Comment: yes,but can't show deeper , like  items in TMenuItem

Comment: Yes it can, I think. Anyway, you are using ancient software, what did you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find one that works the way you want built-in, you can write one yourself quite easily, at least in D7 and later.  I don't have D6 installed to check and what dummzeuch said in a comment about support for debugger visualizers not arriving until later than D6 may be right.

If D6's ToolsApi.Pas *does* support visualizers, first thing to do is to code a form which will take an instance of the object you're interested in and displays it as you wish, including whatever drill-down display you want.

Then, you could follow the example in my D7 answer to this q:

[Can I change the display format for strings in the watch list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33121397/can-i-change-the-display-format-for-strings-in-the-watch-list/33127943)

to prepare an IDE add-in which includes your visualizer and a .DPK to compile it into a design-time package.  That's about it, really.

Comment: Obviously it would be a good idea to try my example before spending any time trying to do your own, just in case there is a show-stopping problem in D6.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly it is not that easy in Delphi 6 (it has been years since I last used Delphi 6). However, have you looked at GExperts? The other way is to type out each public/published field that the object has in the watch window. I don't have access to Delphi 6 but I do have access to Delphi 7 so watch this space.

Comment: Ah I stand corrected. I have not used Delphi 6 since 2012. and I no longer use Gexperts.......

Comment: @DeaaDarawsheh: "only" is not quite right, and its documentation is one of the best sources for information for writing your own add-ins, etc.

Comment: GExperts has got a lot of enhancements (not just for the code editor), but debug visualizers are not included. I'm not even sure whether that is possible in Delphi 6. IIRC the ToolsAPI for debug visualizers was introduced later.

Comment: @dummzeuch: I think you may be right about debug visualizers not arriving until after D6.  I don't have D6 to check, but D5's ToolsApi.Pas certainly doesn't include the visualizer interfaces.